# FFPROBE returns that all I-Frames are IDR frames (KEYFRAME=1) in a TS file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

Running

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_frames -show_streams -unit -select_streams v "D:\CH621.ts" > "D:\CH621.ts.json" -skip_frame nointra
```

Result shows that all 6 I-FRAMES are IDR but professional TS-MPEG analyzer shows that the IDR frames are only 3 on the interval of 2 seconds as configured on the encoder that generates the output.
So, does anyone knows why?

> ffprobe version N-91504-g3735d55af3 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg
>   developers   built with gcc 7.3.1 (GCC) 20180710

FFPROBE result:

```
> {
>     "frames": [
>         {
>             "media_type": "video",
>             "stream_index": 0,
>             "key_frame": 1,
>             "pkt_pts": 936200658,
>             "pkt_pts_time": "10402.229533 s",
>             "pkt_dts": 936371658,
>             "pkt_dts_time": "10404.129533 s",
>             "best_effort_timestamp": 936200658,
>             "best_effort_timestamp_time": "10402.229533 s",
>             "pkt_duration": 3000,
>             "pkt_duration_time": "0.033333 s",
>             "pkt_pos": "752",
>             "pkt_size": "6308 byte",
>             "width": 400,
>             "height": 224,
>             "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
>             "sample_aspect_ratio": "224:225",
>             "pict_type": "I",
>             "coded_picture_number": 0,
>             "display_picture_number": 0,
>             "interlaced_frame": 0,
>             "top_field_first": 0,
>             "repeat_pict": 0,
>             "color_range": "tv",
>             "color_space": "bt709",
>             "color_primaries": "bt709",
>             "color_transfer": "bt709",
>             "chroma_location": "left",
>             "side_data_list": [
>                 {
>                     "side_data_type": "Active format description"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "media_type": "video",
>             "stream_index": 0,
>             "key_frame": 1,
>             "pkt_pts": 936380658,
>             "pkt_pts_time": "10404.229533 s",
>             "pkt_dts": 936386658,
>             "pkt_dts_time": "10404.296200 s",
>             "best_effort_timestamp": 936380658,
>             "best_effort_timestamp_time": "10404.229533 s",
>             "pkt_duration": 3000,
>             "pkt_duration_time": "0.033333 s",
>             "pkt_pos": "169576",
>             "pkt_size": "7285 byte",
>             "width": 400,
>             "height": 224,
>             "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
>             "sample_aspect_ratio": "224:225",
>             "pict_type": "I",
>             "coded_picture_number": 1,
>             "display_picture_number": 0,
>             "interlaced_frame": 0,
>             "top_field_first": 0,
>             "repeat_pict": 0,
>             "color_range": "tv",
>             "color_space": "bt709",
>             "color_primaries": "bt709",
>             "color_transfer": "bt709",
>             "chroma_location": "left",
>             "side_data_list": [
>                 {
>                     "side_data_type": "Active format description"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "media_type": "video",
>             "stream_index": 0,
>             "key_frame": 1,
>             "pkt_pts": 936398658,
>             "pkt_pts_time": "10404.429533 s",
>             "pkt_dts": 936551658,
>             "pkt_dts_time": "10406.129533 s",
>             "best_effort_timestamp": 936398658,
>             "best_effort_timestamp_time": "10404.429533 s",
>             "pkt_duration": 3000,
>             "pkt_duration_time": "0.033333 s",
>             "pkt_pos": "188000",
>             "pkt_size": "21889 byte",
>             "width": 400,
>             "height": 224,
>             "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
>             "sample_aspect_ratio": "224:225",
>             "pict_type": "I",
>             "coded_picture_number": 4,
>             "display_picture_number": 0,
>             "interlaced_frame": 0,
>             "top_field_first": 0,
>             "repeat_pict": 0,
>             "color_range": "tv",
>             "color_space": "bt709",
>             "color_primaries": "bt709",
>             "color_transfer": "bt709",
>             "chroma_location": "left",
>             "side_data_list": [
>                 {
>                     "side_data_type": "Active format description"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "media_type": "video",
>             "stream_index": 0,
>             "key_frame": 1,
>             "pkt_pts": 936560658,
>             "pkt_pts_time": "10406.229533 s",
>             "pkt_dts": 936638658,
>             "pkt_dts_time": "10407.096200 s",
>             "best_effort_timestamp": 936560658,
>             "best_effort_timestamp_time": "10406.229533 s",
>             "pkt_duration": 3000,
>             "pkt_duration_time": "0.033333 s",
>             "pkt_pos": "353064",
>             "pkt_size": "9635 byte",
>             "width": 400,
>             "height": 224,
>             "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
>             "sample_aspect_ratio": "224:225",
>             "pict_type": "I",
>             "coded_picture_number": 5,
>             "display_picture_number": 0,
>             "interlaced_frame": 0,
>             "top_field_first": 0,
>             "repeat_pict": 0,
>             "color_range": "tv",
>             "color_space": "bt709",
>             "color_primaries": "bt709",
>             "color_transfer": "bt709",
>             "chroma_location": "left",
>             "side_data_list": [
>                 {
>                     "side_data_type": "Active format description"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "media_type": "video",
>             "stream_index": 0,
>             "key_frame": 1,
>             "pkt_pts": 936647658,
>             "pkt_pts_time": "10407.196200 s",
>             "pkt_dts": 936689658,
>             "pkt_dts_time": "10407.662867 s",
>             "best_effort_timestamp": 936647658,
>             "best_effort_timestamp_time": "10407.196200 s",
>             "pkt_duration": 3000,
>             "pkt_duration_time": "0.033333 s",
>             "pkt_pos": "440860",
>             "pkt_size": "7583 byte",
>             "width": 400,
>             "height": 224,
>             "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
>             "sample_aspect_ratio": "224:225",
>             "pict_type": "I",
>             "coded_picture_number": 10,
>             "display_picture_number": 0,
>             "interlaced_frame": 0,
>             "top_field_first": 0,
>             "repeat_pict": 0,
>             "color_range": "tv",
>             "color_space": "bt709",
>             "color_primaries": "bt709",
>             "color_transfer": "bt709",
>             "chroma_location": "left",
>             "side_data_list": [
>                 {
>                     "side_data_type": "Active format description"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "media_type": "video",
>             "stream_index": 0,
>             **"key_frame": 1,**
>             "pkt_pts": 936707658,
>             "pkt_pts_time": "10407.862867 s",
>             "best_effort_timestamp": 936707658,
>             "best_effort_timestamp_time": "    s",
>             "pkt_duration": 3000,
>             "pkt_duration_time": "0.033333 s",
>             "pkt_pos": "516060",
>             "pkt_size": "10647 byte",
>             "width": 400,
>             "height": 224,
>             "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
>             "sample_aspect_ratio": "224:225",
>             "pict_type": "I",
>             "coded_picture_number": 15,
>             "display_picture_number": 0,
>             "interlaced_frame": 0,
>             "top_field_first": 0,
>             "repeat_pict": 0,
>             "color_range": "tv",
>             "color_space": "bt709",
>             "color_primaries": "bt709",
>             "color_transfer": "bt709",
>             "chroma_location": "left",
>             "side_data_list": [
>                 {
>                     "side_data_type": "Active format description"
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>     ],
>     "streams": [
>         {
>             "index": 0,
>             "codec_name": "h264",
>             "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
>             "profile": "High",
>             "codec_type": "video",
>             "codec_time_base": "1/60",
>             "codec_tag_string": "[27][0][0][0]",
>             "codec_tag": "0x001b",
>             "width": 400,
>             "height": 224,
>             "coded_width": 400,
>             "coded_height": 224,
>             "has_b_frames": 1,
>             "sample_aspect_ratio": "224:225",
>             "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
>             "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
>             "level": 13,
>             "color_range": "tv",
>             "color_space": "bt709",
>             "color_transfer": "bt709",
>             "color_primaries": "bt709",
>             "chroma_location": "left",
>             "field_order": "progressive",
>             "refs": 4,
>             "is_avc": "false",
>             "nal_length_size": "0",
>             "id": "0x21",
>             "r_frame_rate": "30/1",
>             "avg_frame_rate": "30/1",
>             "time_base": "1/90000",
>             "start_pts": 936200658,
>             "start_time": "10402.229533 s",
>             "duration_ts": 540000,
>             "duration": "6.000000 s",
>             "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
>             "nb_read_frames": "6",
>             "disposition": {
>                 "default": 0,
>                 "dub": 0,
>                 "original": 0,
>                 "comment": 0,
>                 "lyrics": 0,
>                 "karaoke": 0,
>                 "forced": 0,
>                 "hearing_impaired": 0,
>                 "visual_impaired": 0,
>                 "clean_effects": 0,
>                 "attached_pic": 0,
>                 "timed_thumbnails": 0
>             }
>         }
>     ],
>     "format": {
>         "filename": "D:\\CH621.ts",
>         "nb_streams": 4,
>         "nb_programs": 1,
>         "format_name": "mpegts",
>         "format_long_name": "MPEG-TS (MPEG-2 Transport Stream)",
>         "start_time": "10402.229533 s",
>         "duration": "6.010667 s",
>         "size": "586748 byte",
>         "bit_rate": "780942 bit/s",
>         "probe_score": 50
```

Comment: ffmpeg's h264 decoder marks recovery-point frames as KF.